# g:countrySelect with full country name as value

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to store the exact country name using g:countrySelect.  Example Germany instead of DEU.  It is the value in the drop down menu.  The drop down text is Germany but when it saves it to the database it changes back to the country code.  Sorry if I am somewhat naive but I have been searching for almost 3 hours for solutions and it isn't well documented at the grails website.  I could opt for any alternative even ajax. Just to have an easy way to display a list of countries and will be able to store the REAL NAME of the country NOT country code.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can convert from an ISO3 country code to the country name using this function

```
def getCountryName(String countryCode) {
  Locale.availableLocales.find{it.ISO3Country == countryCode}.displayCountry
}

// Test
println getCountryName('DEU')  // prints 'Germany'
```

If you want to do this within a GSP, it would be best to make this available as a TagLib.

Comment: You might have to call toUpperCase() on your country code. By default the countrySelect tag stores the code in lower case.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when the above solution stopped working but if you try that now, you'll get an error:

```
Couldn't find 3-letter country code for CS
```

With the latest grail version, the current way of getting the full country name is by using this tag:

```
<g:country code="${country}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I was looking for the same issue and I had to share my solution.

You can use the [CountryTagLib](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.6/api/org/grails/plugins/web/taglib/CountryTagLib.html) object to convert the ISO3 code back to full country name like this :

```
def country = CountryTagLib.ISO3166_3[code]
```

The "code" property being the ISO3 code that you got from <g:countrySelect>.